# How to: implement sentry 2 permissions with Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I'm trying to use cartalyst sentry 2 in my site being built with Laravel 4. Basically I don't understand how to implement permissions.

The examples I've seen for permissions for a group specify the following as an example:

```
{
    "name" : "Administrator",
    "permissions" : 
    {
        "user.create" : 1,
        "user.delete" : 1,
        "user.view"   : 1,
        "user.update" : 1
    }
}
```

SO this is setting permissions for the admin group. BUT where are these permissions set?

In the table 'groups' there is a field called permissions which is a text field - are they set there - if so how? Or are these set in a model or controller?

Can anyone point me to s step by step on how to use in a laravel 4 app? I've read the supporting docs which foes through the functions but I'm just not sure how to set the data to get the functions to work.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Basically you have to..

Create your groups

```
Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create([
    'name' => 'Super Administrators',
    'permissions' => [
        'system' => 1,
    ],
]);

Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create([
    'name' => 'Managers',
    'permissions' => [
        'system.products' => 1,
        'system.store' => 1,
        'system.profile' => 1,
    ],
]);
```

Set a group to a particular user, in this case it is setting Managers to the current logged user

```
Sentry::getUser()->addGroup( Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('Managers') );
```

Check if a user has a particular access

```
if ( Sentry::getUser()->hasAnyAccess(['system','system.products']) )
{
    // Will be able to do a thing
}
```

Check if a user is Super Administrator (only this group has the 'system' access)

```
if ( Sentry::getUser()->hasAnyAccess(['system']) )
{
    // Will be able to do a thing
}
```

Get all groups from a particular user

```
try
{
    // Find the user using the user id
    $user = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findById(1);

    // Get the user groups
    $groups = $user->getGroups();
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
{
    echo 'User was not found.';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this info - I'll try this out and implement. Just for clarity - are the names you use related to classes or simply descriptors unique to an app and can be anything?

Comment: Are you talking about `system`, `system.products`...? There's no relation between them and your classes, those are just names you pick. I'm trying to be granular using them like `system.products.insert`, if you have `system.products`, you can do everything on products.

Comment: I was looking for this all day

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro Awesome :D In case if i want to set a group for particular user email? instead of logged in user. Thx!!

Comment: You can set it to the group name: `'name' => 'me@mydomain.com'`.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro I mean assign the user to the group, like user (me@mydomain.com) add to admin group, not loggoed user

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro Thx, found it in the user update section.. i still wondering why it's not documented xD

Comment: What is the return type of `getGroups()`?

Comment: It will return an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection.

Comment: Why isn't this in Sentry documentation?!??!  Thanks!

Comment: is there maybe a way to implement a multiple filter that will return the route in case that at least one filter is true? For example like this:
Route::get('users', array('as' => 'getUsers', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getIndex', 'before' => 'inGroup:Administrator|hasAccess:users.index'));
or do i need also for the admin group define all these permissions which are also in other groups? Now I have only 1 for admin group which is global so admin can access to everything and specific for other groups

Answer (score 4):

In your `groups` table you set the permissions using JSON.

I have the following columns:

`id | name | permissions`

And a row:

`1 | admin | {"admin":1, "create_news": 1}`

Assign a user to a group using the table `users_groups`

Now you can use the following example to check if a user have a given permission:

```
$user = Sentry::getUser();
if ($user->hasAccess('create_news')) {
    echo "You can create a news item";
}
else {
    echo "You can't create a news item";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I'm going to use a combination of the two answers, both make sense. Now to trial it in my site.